# Creating a materialized view for calculating histogram data

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE results
(
    id UUID,
    date_time DateTime,
    item_id UInt32,
    value UInt16
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date_time)
ORDER BY (date_time, item_id);
```

And I want to create a materialized view to store hourly histogram data for value. For example;

I expect an output like this:

```
toStartOfHour          item_id    value    count
2019-12-18 00:00:00    1          0        4       /* number of rows with value between 0 and 100 and date_time between 2019-12-18 00:00:00 and 2019-12-18 01:00:00 */
2019-12-18 00:00:00    1          100      7       /* number of rows with value between 100 and 200 and date_time between 2019-12-18 00:00:00 and 2019-12-18 01:00:00 */
```

Number of rows with `value` between 100 and 0, and `date_time` between `2019-12-18 00:00:00` and `2019-12-18 01:00:00`. I have tried something like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW results_histogram_by_hour
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date_time)
ORDER BY (date_time, item_id)
POPULATE
AS SELECT toStartOfHour(date_time) AS date_time,
          item_id,
          multiply(floor(value / 100), 100) AS value,
          countState() AS count
FROM results
GROUP BY date_time,
         item_id,
         value;
```

This materialized view definition works when populated. But with time and new rows, it gets wrong. How wrong? I don't know. I couldn't find a pattern.

I am not sure if I found a bug on clickhouse or I am doing something wrong.

Is my materialized view definition correct?

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8278

Should be ORDER BY (date_time, item_id, value)

Answer (score 2):

AggregatingMT uses order by (primary key) as `Dimensions` all other columns are `Metrics`. If metric column does not have State function it will be calculated / collapsed by `ANY`

```
CREATE table results_histogram_by_hour
(date_time DateTime,
 item_id UInt32,
 value UInt16,
 count AggregateFunction(count) 
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date_time) 
ORDER BY (date_time, item_id)

insert into results_histogram_by_hour 
select toStartOfHour(now()) date_time,
       1 item_id,
       1 value,
       countState()
group by date_time, item_id, value;

insert into results_histogram_by_hour 
select toStartOfHour(now()) date_time,
       1 item_id,
      99 value,
       countState()
group by date_time, item_id, value;

optimize table results_histogram_by_hour final;

select * from results_histogram_by_hour;

┌───────────date_time─┬─item_id─┬─value─┬─count─┐
│ 2019-12-18 21:00:00 │       1 │     1 │       │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┘

ORDER BY (date_time, item_id , value)
┌───────────date_time─┬─item_id─┬─value─┬─count─┐
│ 2019-12-18 21:00:00 │       1 │     1 │       │
│ 2019-12-18 21:00:00 │       1 │    99 │       │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

If one does not like the idea of long/wide/haevy index (PRIMARYKEY) one can use different set of columns for ORDERBY/PRIMARYKEY. All ENGINEs use ORDERBY column set for Merges/collapsing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/summingmergetree/#nested-structures

SummingMergeTree able to sum values in K/V arrays 
(columns should be named ...Map -- value**Map**)

```
CREATE TABLE results
(
    id UInt64,
    date_time DateTime,
    item_id UInt32,
    value UInt16
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date_time)
ORDER BY (date_time, item_id);


insert into results 
select number,
       now(),
       number%7 item_id,
       number%9957 value
from numbers(10000);


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW results_histogram_by_hour
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date_time)
ORDER BY (date_time, item_id) POPULATE AS
SELECT
    date_time,
    item_id,
    groupArray(value) AS `valueMap.bin`,
    groupArray(cnt) AS `valueMap.cnt`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toStartOfHour(date_time) AS date_time,
        item_id,
        intDiv(value, 1000) AS value,
        sum(toUInt64(1)) AS cnt
    FROM results
    GROUP BY
        date_time,
        item_id,
        value
)
GROUP BY
    date_time,
    item_id


insert into results 
select number,
       now(),
       number%7 item_id,
       number%9957 value
from numbers(10000);

SELECT *
FROM results_histogram_by_hour
WHERE item_id = 4

─item_id─┬─valueMap.bin──────────┬─valueMap.cnt──────────────────────────────┐
       4 │ [0,7,6,1,5,2,3,4,8,9] │ [149,143,143,143,143,142,143,143,143,136] │
─────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘
─item_id─┬─valueMap.bin──────────┬─valueMap.cnt──────────────────────────────┐
       4 │ [0,7,6,1,5,2,3,4,8,9] │ [149,143,143,143,143,142,143,143,143,136] │
─────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘    

SELECT
    date_time,
    item_id,
    sumMap(valueMap.bin, valueMap.cnt)
FROM results_histogram_by_hour
WHERE item_id = 4
GROUP BY
    date_time,
    item_id

─item_id─┬─sumMap(valueMap.bin, valueMap.cnt)────────────────────────────────┐
       4 │ ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[298,286,284,286,286,286,286,286,286,272]) │
─────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

optimize table results_histogram_by_hour final;

SELECT *
FROM results_histogram_by_hour
WHERE item_id = 4

─item_id─┬─valueMap.bin──────────┬─valueMap.cnt──────────────────────────────┐
       4 │ [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] │ [298,286,284,286,286,286,286,286,286,272] │
─────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```